# Ether.js works fine on desktop but not with metamask app (android/ios)

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I noticed that my little vanilla JS script to get people to connect to my "dapp" works fine on desktop with metamask, but doesn't work with metamask mobile app.

It gives me an error as if the "Provider" was not set.

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const connectbtn = document.querySelector('.connectbtn');
connectbtn.addEventListener('click',enabler);

async function enabler(){
    
        try {
  await ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
    params: [{ chainId: '0x38' }],
  });
} catch (switchError) {
  // This error code indicates that the chain has not been added to MetaMask.
  if (error.code === 4902) {
    try {
      await ethereum.request({
        method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
        params: [{ chainId: '0x38', rpcUrl: 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/' /* ... */ }],
      });
    } catch (addError) {
      // handle "add" error
    }
  }
  // handle other "switch" errors
}
 doing();
 
};

async function doing() {
    await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);

    
    
    let addressconnected = document.querySelector(".addressConnected") ;
    addressconnected.innerHTML =`Connected`;
    

    // console.log("Account:", await signer.getAddress());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `window.ethereum` does not exist on mobile. it's only available on desktop web browsers.
i believe that there are several ways:

1- Try to connect to Metamask on mobile via wallet connect.

2- if you're using React, use **@react-web3/core** to interact with it in a convinent way.

3- the official docs recommends to use **@metamask/detect-provider**

**Note**: reach out this [link](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/mobile-best-practices.html#the-provider-window-ethereum)

**A tricky note:** it seems connecting to a wallet via wallet connect on mobile, should requires us to switching your dApp's url to https.
it happens to me after switching it with the same code :)

**If it's useful vote up plz :)**